# Cutting Recipes exercise on CodeChef

Tags: c, arrays, greatest-common-divisor

The following is [my solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/10859412) to [a problem on codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/RECIPE/).
I am getting the correct output on my computer but not on codechef.
I couldn't find the mistake in my code.

The problem is to divide an array by the GCD of its elements and print it.

I wrote the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int t,n;
  scanf("%d",&t);

  while(t--)
  {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n],i,divisor,curr,r;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    divisor = a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
      curr = a[i];
      if(curr<divisor)
      {
        divisor = curr;
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      r = a[i]%divisor;
      if(r != 0){
        divisor = 1;
        break;
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
      printf("%d ",a[i]/divisor);
    }

    printf("%d\n",a[n-1]/divisor);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

- `t` is the number of test cases.
- `n` is the length of the array.
- `a[n]` is the array.
- `divisor` is the GCD of all the elements in the array.
- `curr` is the current number tested.
- `r` is the remainder.

*Sample Input*

```
3  
2 4 4  
3 2 3 4  
4 3 15 9 6
```

*Sample Output*

```
1 1  
2 3 4  
1 5 3 2
```

Comment: Make a separate function to calculate GCDs and use it. Give your variables actual names. With these two steps, your bug has a much better chance of being obvious or resolved.

Comment: You were mislead by the sample input, the GCD is not just the smallest element in the array. A better example would be this array with four elements: {6,9,21,15}. The expected output is: {2,3,7,5}.

Comment: Please give your question a better title. "What is wrong with this code?" basically describes everything on this site. Another user with the same problem will have no way of finding this question.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track thinking it was an exercise involving CGD ( greatest common divisor ).

However you misunderstand on how to calculate the GCD.
it is rarely the smallest element of an array .

For example:

```
15, 6, 9
```

The smallest element is `6` and is not a common divisor of the other element ( and would have chosen `1` as a divisor in your case ), but the gcd in this case is `3`

You could start by reading some information about calculating the [CGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of a pair of element. And one [example implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).

Then try to figure out how to calculate the GCD of all the element of an array.

These hints could help